# Is there a compile warning about this use of std::move?

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, c++builder

The following program shows two problematic (but technically valid) uses of `std::move()`. Is it possible to get a compile warning about these with LLVM? I have noticed that there is diagnostic for some other contexts where `std::move` is redundant.

I compiled this with bcc32c version 5.0.2 (based on LLVM 5.0.2) and received no warnings.

```
#include <vector>

int main() {
    const std::vector<int> a = {1, 2, 3};
    std::vector<int> b = {3, 4, 5};

    std::vector<int> c = std::move(a); // std::move from const

    std::vector<int> d = std::move(b);

    std::vector<int> e = b; // used after std::move
}
```

Comment: The second case is hard to diagnose. Classes _may_ specify that the state after a move is well-defined; `std::unique_ptr<T>` is an example.

Comment: The 2nd case is also well defined for `std::vector<T>`.

Comment: The code analyser in Visual Studio (but using clang-cl) spots the second case: **warning G8547E8E7: Moved-from object 'b' of type 'std::vector' is copied [clang-analyzer-cplusplus.Move]  std::vector<int> e = b; // used after std::move**

Comment: @juanchopanza Well-defined, but probably unintentional. That's why I want to detect it.

Comment: Interesting issue, I never thought about. I made a [MCVE on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1f97bd2bec59c3f2) to illustrate the effects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

clang-tidy's [`bugprone-use-after-move`](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/bugprone-use-after-move.html) checker supports this kind of diagnostic:

> **`bugprone-use-after-move`**
>
> Warns if an object is used after it has been moved, for example:
>
> ```
> std::string str = "Hello, world!\n";
> std::vector<std::string> messages;
> messages.emplace_back(std::move(str));
> std::cout << str;
> ```
>
> The last line will trigger a warning that str is used after it has
>   been moved.
>
> [...]
>
> **Use**
>
> Any occurrence of the moved variable that is not a reinitialization (see below) is considered to be a use.
>
> [...]
>
> If multiple uses occur after a move, only the first of these is flagged.

Answer (score 4):

clang-tidy has a [`performance-move-const-arg`](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/performance-move-const-arg.html) check which warns:

> 1. if std::move() is called with a constant argument,
> 2. if std::move() is called with an argument of a trivially-copyable type,
> 3. if the result of std::move() is passed as a const reference argument.
>
> In all three cases, the check will suggest a fix that removes the std::move().

with the following examples:

> ```cpp
> const string s;
> return std::move(s);  // Warning: std::move of the const variable has no effect
>
> int x;
> return std::move(x);  // Warning: std::move of the variable of a trivially-copyable type has no effect
>
> void f(const string &s);
> string s;
> f(std::move(s));      // Warning: passing result of std::move as a const reference argument; no move will actually happen
> ```

Comment: Hello, can you explain why I get the same warning on the 2nd one, when x is a struct defined as a POD type? E.g. `struct {int i, int j} x;`. I still want it to be passed as an rvalue so why don't I need `std::move(x)` in that case? How can I be sure it's an rvalue?

Comment: It's even worse, if I don't specify `std::move` when passing it as an lvalue, you get a compiler warning. Apparently it's a known issue of this clang-tidy check https://reviews.llvm.org/D107450!! :o